# STBC Rank Criteria Explanation

Tags: linear-algebra, mimo, coding

I am learning about space-time block coding and I am trying to understand why the rank criteria is a good measure of diversity gain. I know that we want to maximize the distance between codewords $X_i, X_j$, and I understand that $G_{ij} = (X_i - X_j)^H (X_i - X_j)$ is "bigger" when the two codewords are further apart, but i don't see how $rank(G_{ij})$ measures this matrix's "bigness."

Why does rank measure codeword detection error? It seems like we would want to consider the size of the values in $G_{ij}$, but this measure doesn't do that. Is there some eigenvalue stuff going on behind the scenes that I'm not seeing?

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: It has to do with the number of non-zero eigenvalues. If it is not full rank, some eigenvalues will be zero, and thus the diversity won't equal the number of transmit antennas (full diversity). Refer to chapter 3 in the book Space-Time Coding: Theory and Practice, Hamid Jafarkhani.

Answer (score 0):

[First shot] What I like with SE.DSP is that you can try to answer questions on topics you know nothing about. And I know nothing about space-time block coding. But I'll dig into the papers to be more precise later, since I am quite interested in concepts like diversity, redundancy, sparsity.

Most signal processing algorithms reside in the gray area between: "what you really want" and "what you can reasonably achieve". Sometimes, what you want is not computable, or difficult to model, and most of your DSP  work consists in finding a "good-enough" proxy to satisfy both goals. This the modelling and optimization part of DSP.

Concepts like *diversity*, *redundancy*, *sparsity* are rather vague, and could formalized in many and very different ways, depending in the objective. One acceptation of diversity is: how good am I at describing the richness of the space of possibilities? **Good** may means: do I describe the space of possibilities as much as I can (with respect to my dimension) or do I describe this space efficiently?

Let us be more concrete. In a 2D linear space, I only need two basis vectors to describe all other vectors, by linear combination. Wait, not any tow vectors. Two that are not co-linear. Two (and more vectors) that are colinear, or linearly dependent, have lower rank. 
And we do not care about the size of the vectors. So basically, **the rank is one mathematical object that both**:

- check how much a set of vectors is not colinear
- does not really bother about their actual size (if $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are not colinear, $\vec{a}$ and $10^{-6} \vec{b}$ ae not as well)

So, the issue is not about being big (as scalar factors barely matter), but being "spread" (or dense).

I'll be back latter, building on parts of: [Space–Time Codes for High Data Rate Wireless Communication: Performance Criterion and Code Construction](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=661517),  IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON INFORMATION THEORY, VOL. 44, NO. 2, MARCH 1998